# Not close dropdown on selection of a checkbox element?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

This is an easy question. I am using bootstrap v3.2.0 to creating a list of checkboxes on a navbar dropdown menu.

I was just wondering if there is a way of not snapping the checkbox away after clicking on each checkbox.

I have provided the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/5649/

```
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-btn">
                            <button tabindex="-1" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Select</button>
                            <button tabindex="-1" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button">
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                            <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">
                                <input type="checkbox"><span class="lbl"> Every day</span>
                                </a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">
                                <input type="checkbox">
                                <span class="lbl"> Monday</span>
                            </a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">
                                <input type="checkbox"><span class="lbl">
                                Tuesday</span>
                                </a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">
                                <input type="checkbox"><span class="lbl">
                                Wednesday</span>
                                </a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">
                                <input type="checkbox"><span class="lbl">
                                Thursday</span>
                                </a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">
                                <input type="checkbox"><span class="lbl">
                                Friday</span>
                                </a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">
                                <input type="checkbox"><span class="lbl">
                                Saturday</span>
                                </a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">
                                <input type="checkbox"><span class="lbl">
                                Sunday</span>
                            </a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">
                                <input type="checkbox"><span class="lbl"> Last Weekday in month</span>
</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div>
```

Will accept the first answer that works correctly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just need to prevent event bubbling:

```
$('.dropdown-menu').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Where `dropdown-menu` is a class of your dropdown, you can specify another or use id instead. The reason why it works is that Bootrstrap listens click event on root element `body` in order to close popup when you click on the page. Due to event bubbling click event propagates up the DOM tree to the very `body` unless you stop it from doing it with `stopPropagation` method.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/7040/